# roots of the equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I was wondering if $\cot z=\alpha z$ has any root(s) in $\mathbb{C}$?. Here $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ a fixed constant.
Is there a way to find it in case it exists?.

Comment: The equation above is equivalent to $\cos z-\alpha z \sin z=0$ and it follows from general theory of entire functions that it has infinitely many zeroes for any $\alpha$; not sure that there is any simple formula but one can give estimates on the number of zeroes, narrow down small discs where said zeroes are located etc by standard theory too

Comment: @ Conrad ... How does it follow?. Moreover, cot is not an entire function. What allows us to re-express it as $\cos z-\alpha z\sin z$?. Assuming that it can be written in the form represented by you, which property of analytic function is allowing it?. It has infinite roots when treated as a function of one variable for sure. Apologies for any silly query.

Comment: Just write the equation as $\cos z/\sin z= \alpha z$ and simplify the $\sin$ noting that $k\pi$ is never a root of the new equation; then the new equation becomes $f_{\alpha}(z)=0$ for an entire $f_{\alpha}$ and if has only finitely many zeroes, it is $Pe^g$ for some polynomial $P$ and entire $g$ and that easily leads to contradiction by bashing it out with limits at various infinities etc; you can use more advanced theory or use Jensen to deduce more about number of roots etc,; same proof shows the result for $\cot z=\alphsa Q(z)$ for any non constant polynomial $Q$

Comment: $\cot z=\alpha Q$ above of course

Comment: Thank you very much @Conrad

Comment: Happy to be of help